# Why do datestr(x) and datestr(x,'hh:mm:ss') in Matlab have different time result?

Tags: matlab

I have the following date in serial numbers

```
>> x

x =

7.3506e+05
```

and below are the two different results:

```
>> datestr(x)

ans =

11-Jul-2012 15:58:00

>> datestr(x,'hh:mm:ss')

ans =

15:07:00
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `mm` means "Month in two digits", and since the month is July, "07" is correct.

Use upper case for time: "HH:MM:SS"

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#input_argument_formatout

```
>> x
x =    7.3506e+05
>> datestr(x)
ans = 11-Jul-2012 15:58:00
>> datestr(x,'HH:MM:SS')
ans = 15:58:00
```